# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico (“default-src”)

Tags: java, spring-boot, web

Why I am getting this error when I run my Spring Boot web application
[image: Result]

I am running my app on firefox, I tried it on [Brave](https://brave.com/) and Google Chrome it is same there too.

Comment: You should add http://localhost:8080 to your CSP.

Comment: @ControlAltDel will you tell me how to do it, i am beginner in Spring Boot